# How can I add/update a submodule, using an existing repository to save bandwidth?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Say I have some big repo, BigRepo, and I want to add it as a submodule for another project.  Normally I would do

```
$ git submodule add git@somewhere.com/me/BigRepo.git
```

but I don't want to download the whole thing again.  Luckily I already have a checkout of it, so I try

```
$ git clone ../BigRepo
Cloning into 'BigRepo'...
done.
$ git submodule add git@somewhere.com/me/BigRepo.git
Adding existing repo at 'BigRepo' to the index
```

Great!  Except

1. The `origin` remote in the submodule points to `../BigRepo`; I'd like it to point to `git@somewhere.com/...`
2. The `.git` folder is in `BigRepo/.git` instead of `.git/modules/BigRepo`

So what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's going to be a little fixup to do because you're wanting to discard all the evidence of that proxy repo (`../BigRepo`), but it's not hard.

Easiest from here is probably to just redo the submodule add with what you have, do that by

```
# undo the in-repo add
mv BigRepo ../agggh_I_meant_to_add_this_from_outside
git rm --cached BigRepo
git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.BigRepo
git config                --remove-section submodule.BigRepo
```

And your backout is complete.

Now, if you add a submodule from a local, unpublished repo you have to then correct the urls later for the convenience of others, but that's straightforward:

```
# Get `git submodule add` to do the hoisting for you
git submodule add ../agggh_* BigRepo

# but from now on use u://r/l as the submodule's published repo:
git config -f .gitmodules --set submodule.BigRepo.url u://r/l
git config                --set submodule.BigRepo.url u://r/l  # alternate spelling of `git submodule sync BigRepo` here

# and the published repo is my copy's `origin` too
git --git-dir=BigRepo/.git remote set-url origin u://r/l
```

---

(

edit addressing questions in comments:

The `mv`/clone-from-the-mv'd-one pair is because perhaps you've done, or done and forgotten, some work there, and so `../BigRepo` might be out-of-date.  It's just a safety play; a `rm -rf BigRepo` and later `git submodule add ../BigRepo` would work as well if the currently-added one is really discardable.

I can't figure how any of the submodule adds above could provoke network activity -- `../anything` is on the same filesystem as `../ThisRepo` i.e. `.`, right?  `git clone` of a plain same-filesystem path, relative or absolute, does dirt-cheap hardlinks unless you take steps to provoke an actual copy -- this works even on NTFS. It's only if you specify a full url or otherwise force the issue that git creates a full-copy clone.  Maybe it's just the caffeine kicking in unusually slowly, if I'm missing something please, whoever sees it, just edit it in or edit this whole paragraph out.

)

Comment: Thanks, this works great!  But assuming I have some more submodules to add in the same way, what's the best way to do this from a clean slate, so to speak?  `git submodule add ../BigRepo` re-clones it over the network.  Is there a better way than cloning `../BigRepo` to `../BigRepoCopy` and then adding it?

Comment: Actually never mind, turns out git treats `../BigRepo` as relative to `origin`.  If you do `git submodule add /full/path/to/BigRepo` it works as expected.