# Add existing git repo as submodule

Tags: git, shell, git-submodules

I am reorganizing my dotfiles and have the following directory structure:

```
dotfiles
├── .vim
│   ├── colors/
│   ├── ftplugin/
│   ├── pack/
│   │   └── my_plugins/
│   │       ├── opt/
│   │       │   ├── nerdtree/
│   │       │   │   ├── .git
│   │       │   └── vimwiki/
│   │       │       ├── .git
│   │       └── start/
│   │           ├── fugitive/
│   │           │   ├── .git
│   │           ├── syntastic/
│   │           │   ├── .git
│   │           ├── vimade/
│   │           │   ├── .git
│   │           └── vim-css-color/
│   │               ├── .git
│   ├── README.md
│   └── vimrc
```

There are six directories which are github repos and that have already been cloned to their directories.

I want to now make the entire dotfiles directory version controlled.
How do I add the six `.../.git` repos as submodules to the top level repo, without having to re-clone the packages.

Note that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776018/how-to-git-submodule-add-existing-sub-repository), a similar question was asked, but the instructions given are unclear.
What I need is the step-by-step solution to add the entire .vim directory to the top-level repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a step by step process :

```
# dotfiles directory is current directory
git init 

# Add already cloned repos
git submodule add <github-repo1-link> <path-to-already-cloned-repo1>
git submodule add <github-repo2-link> <path-to-already-cloned-repo2>
.
.
.

# Add other files for staging
git add .

# Commit the changes
git commit
```

As mentioned in git docs for submodules [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt), the add command of submodule takes path as an optional argument.

```
git submodule add <repository> [<path>]
```

> The optional argument `<path>` is the relative location for the cloned
> submodule to exist in the superproject. If `<path>` is not given, the
> canonical part of the source repository is used ("repo" for
> "/path/to/repo.git" and "foo" for "host.xz:foo/.git"). **If `<path>`
> exists and is already a valid Git repository, then it is staged for
> commit without cloning.** The `<path>` is also used as the submodule’s
> logical name in its configuration entries unless --name is used to
> specify a logical name.